# variance of a random variable

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

If $X_1, X_2 , ....., X_n$ iid $N(0,1)$ , and $S^2$ was defined as the population standard deviation 
we are to find the variance of $S^2$

I want to know the distribution in order to find the variance, may anybody help me?

Comment: are you sure that this is the correct question?

Comment: yes it is! what do u think? can u see any problem in it?

Comment: The question appears to be ill-defined. If $S^2$ is the population standard deviation (as you claim), then it is a constant, not a random variable, and so $Var(S^2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample variance ($S^2$) satisfies that $$(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(n-1)$$

Then $Var(S^2)=Var\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{1}\chi^2(n-1)\right)=\frac{\sigma^4}{n-1}$

In your case $\sigma^2=1$.

you  can find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) almost at the bottom of the page

Comment: you are welcome!